# Error Adding an AzureAD user in my NetCore App?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-graph-api

New to .net Core WebApp, I am attempting to leverage code below but I am getting error when attempting to check user.  I check twice, the first time with an account that exists

Here is the code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace JBSTestAdLoginVSApp.Controllers
{
    public class NewAccountController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        //public String Index()
        {
            return View();
            //return "This is my default action...";
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async void Index(string userPrincipal, string displayName, string mailNickName, string password)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = string.Format("Name: {0} {1} {2} {3}", userPrincipal, displayName, mailNickName, password);
            await Test();
            return;// View();
        }
        private static async Task<string> AppAuthenticationAsync()
        {
            //  Constants
            var tenant = "**************.onmicrosoft.com";  //grabbed from Azure AD
            var resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
            var clientID = "62***********";  //created app and grand read write perms
            var secret = "******";  //added secret to app id

            //  Ceremony
            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}";
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientID, secret);
            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credentials);

            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
        private static async Task<bool> DoesUserExistsAsync(HttpClient client, string user)
        {
            try
            {
                var payload = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}");//fails here with Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

                return true;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private static async Task<string[]> GetUserGroupsAsync(HttpClient client, string user)
        {
            var payload = await client.GetStringAsync(
                $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/memberOf");
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(payload);
            var groupDescription = from g in obj["value"]
                                   select g["displayName"].Value<string>();

            return groupDescription.ToArray();
        }
        private static async Task CreateUserAsync(HttpClient client, string user, string domain)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                var payload = new
                {
                    accountEnabled = true,
                    displayName = user,
                    mailNickname = user,
                    userPrincipalName = $"{user}@{domain}",
                    passwordProfile = new
                    {
                        forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                        password = "tempPa$$w0rd"
                    }
                };
                var payloadText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

                writer.Write(payloadText);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                using (var content = new StreamContent(stream))
                {
                    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/", content);

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static async Task Test()
        {
            //var token = await AppAuthenticationAsync();

            var token = await AppAuthenticationAsync();

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var userA = "Test@*****.onmicrosoft.com";//this account exists
                var userExistA = await DoesUserExistsAsync(client, userA);

                var user = "NewUser1@********.onmicrosoft.com";//this account doesnt
                var userExist = await DoesUserExistsAsync(client, user);

                Console.WriteLine($"Does user exists?  {userExist}");

                if (userExist)
                {
                    var groups = await GetUserGroupsAsync(client, user);

                    foreach (var g in groups)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Group:  {g}");
                    }


                } else
                {
                    await CreateUserAsync(client, "newuser", "******.onmicrosoft.com");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure is I created app reg correctly cause when DoesUserExistsAsync runs it gives  Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

When I assign permissions for the app
[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjLxy.png)

Note that the app says read and write directory data "Not granted for Default directory", I am using a Default Directory, is this the issue?

Answer (score 0):

after you grant an application permission, you have to click grant admin consent for default directory button. otherwise it won't work, if you don't grant consent, the the graph api permission won't have permission to read any of the users.

[image]

If the user doesn't exist, that is correct behavior as the httprequestexception gets called if you don't get success eg 404.. if you try to hit graph endpoint with user who doesn't exist it will return 404, which will trigger the httpexception as you've seen. Also if you don't have permissions to read all users, (because you haven't consented), then it will act as though it found nothing which will again return 404.

once you consent for the organization and search for a user that exists, it should return true.

Comment: I tried that to no effect, in fact it only added that level by changing the second permisisons to read instead of readwrite, , so then I removed the first permission and now I get a bad request when testing.  My current permisison is Name:ReadWrite, Admin consent:yes, Status Granted for Default dir...

Comment: i just looked at your screenshot. you are using the wrong permissions. you need User.readwrite.all not Directory.readwrite.all.